# PHP Checkbox ordered by click and send thru post form to a news sql query on the clicked order

Tags: php, forms, post, checkbox

I have a code on `page1.php` where I have an array of checkbox populated with mysql data through a query. I can successfully submit the value of the checked checkbox to the `page2.php`. But I want to submit it according to the sequence the checkbox was checked by the user. I´ve seen that jQuery can do this, but i don´t know how and where to place the jQuery code.

My intention is to show on `page2.php` what the user selected, on a specific order, from the `page1.php` form

MODIFIED: Well , I managed to create the list and send via form . The problem now is to put a comma between the numbers . I know this must be the easiest problem to solve , but I can not yet.

The SQL Query is looking like this, for example:

> SELECT * FROM emp WHERE id IN (7,9,30) ORDER BY FIELD (id,
>   30 9 7)

**page1.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var listCheckedOptions = [];

function addToList(checkObj, outputObjID) {
    //Remove from array if the element already in.
    if (listCheckedOptions.indexOf(checkObj) >= 0) {
        listCheckedOptions.splice(listCheckedOptions.indexOf(checkObj), 1);
    } 

    listCheckedOptions.push(checkObj);

    document.getElementById(outputObjID).value = ""; //Clean textarea
    document.getElementById(outputObjID).value = listCheckedOptions.map(function (o) {
        return o.value;
    }).join('\r\n'); //Add to textarea
    if (!checkObj.checked) checkObj.nextSibling.querySelector('span').innerHTML = '';
    listCheckedOptions.forEach(function (el, i) {
        var span = el.nextSibling.querySelector('span').innerHTML = i + 1;
    });

    return;
}
</script>

    <?php
    $query = "SELECT * FROM imoveis";
    $result = mysql_query($query,$conn);
    ?>

    <form action="page2.php" method="post">

    <input type="submit" value="Create" id="enviarButton"/></td>

    <br><br>

    <table border="1">
        <?
        $i = 0;

        echo "<tr>";

             while($imovel = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

                $name = $imovel['emp'];
                $id = $imovel['id'];

    ?>   

            <td>
                <?=$name;?><br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="op_imovel[]" value="<?=$id;?>" onClick="addToList(this, 'txt1')">
            </td>
    <?
               $i++;
               if(($i % 3) == 0){
                      echo "</tr><tr>";
                      }
               }

    mysql_close();

    ?>

    </table>
    <br>
    <input type="hidden" name="txt1" id="txt1">

    </form>
```

**page2.php**

```
<?php
  $checkbox = $_POST['op_imovel'];
  $lista = $_POST['txt1'];

  if (is_array($checkbox) && count($checkbox) > 0){
        $res = '';
        $tot = count($checkbox) - 1;
        for ($y = 0; $y <= $tot; $y++) {

            $res .=$checkbox[$y];

            if ($y < $tot)
                $res .= ",";
        }

    }


  $query = "SELECT * FROM emp WHERE id IN ($res) ORDER BY FIELD (id, $lista)";
  $result = mysql_query($query,$conn);
?>

<br>


<div align="center">

        <table border="1">

<?
$i = 0;
echo "<tr>";

    if (is_array($checkbox) && count($checkbox) > 0){
        while($imovel = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 

            $name = ($imovel['emp']);
?>
                <td>
                    <p>
                        <?= $name;?>
                    </p>

                </td>
<?
           $i++;
           if(($i % 3) == 0){
                  echo "</tr><tr>";
           }


        }       

    }   
?>      


</div>

<?  mysql_close(); ?>
```

Comment: Where is your `jQuery` code? Was have you already tried? Nobody wants to write the whole code for you.

Comment: i´ve tried `onclick='javascript:setorder(this)`

Comment: I don´t know jQuery. I´ve tried some codes from this topic, but without success. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12189152/identify-checked-checkbox-sequence-then-save-to-mysql-database

Comment: I just made some changes, but still not working

Comment: Have found the right code and already got it working . I just need to place commas between the numbers.

Comment: Problem solved, took off '\r\n' from .join()